# transformation of flow cytometry data using flowCore?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I wanna know if someone know how to do transformation of the channel four (FLH 4) without using the standard transformations offer by the flowCore package?

The values of the channel four are between 1 and 4096 and i need to convert in values between 1 and 246 with the rule 10^(x/1024).

Thank you.

Comment: If there is no response here, consider asking questions about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/)

Answer (score 2):

Better to use flowTrans mclMultivArcSinh transformation.

```
trans<-flowTrans(flowData, "mclMultivArcSinh",colnames(flowData)[3:12], n2f=FALSE, parameters.only=FALSE)
```

You must not tranform FSC-A,SSC-A and Time thats why i have colnames [3:12].

Answer (score 0):

you could get a custom transform in by doing something like..

> plot(transform(someFlowFrame, `FSC-H`=10^(`FSC-H`/1024), `SSC-H`=10^(`SSC-H`/1024)), c("FSC-H","SSC-H"))

however as 10^(4096/1024) returns a max value of 10000 for your hypothetical example, the plot with your ranges -

> plot(transform(someFlowFrame, `FSC-H`=10^(`FSC-H`/1024), `SSC-H`=10^(`SSC-H`/1024)), c("FSC-H","SSC-H"), xlim=c(0,256), ylim=c(0,256))

doesn't look good.